# What does super(key: key) do in the initialiser list for a constructor in flutter?

Tags: flutter, key, super

Take this code for example:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

 MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   //returns widget
 }
}
```

**What I know** 
`MyApp` is constructor for the class which has field `key`. Initializer list consists of `super(key: key)`. 
So does it mean that I am assigning the `key` of `MyApp` to the `key` of its super constructor?
Is the super constructor `StatelessWidget`?
Why do we need to assign `key` to the `super`?
What happens if I don't do this initializing?

I am new to flutter and am trying to understand how things work, and why.
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take a look at this post, it explain more than it is needed.

[what is Key parameter in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428455/what-is-key-parameter-in-the-constructor)