# Flutter Dart constructor

Tags: dart, flutter

In the flutter Examples page, there is a project entitled "Sending Data to a new screen".  I have question reguarding the constructor on line 65.

[Sending Data to a new screen](https://flutter.io/cookbook/navigation/passing-data/)

```
  // In the constructor, require a Todo
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);
```

What is the super(key: key)?  Could I get explanation of the entire line please.  The Code is here....

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Todo {
  final String title;
  final String description;

  Todo(this.title, this.description);
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Passing Data',
    home: TodosScreen(
      todos: List.generate(
        20,
            (i) => Todo(
          'Todo $i',
          'A description of what needs to be done for Todo $i',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class TodosScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Todo> todos;

  TodosScreen({Key key, @required this.todos}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todos'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: todos.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(todos[index].title),
            // When a user taps on the ListTile, navigate to the DetailScreen.
            // Notice that we're not only creating a DetailScreen, we're
            // also passing the current todo through to it!
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailScreen(todo: todos[index]),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a field that holds the Todo
  final Todo todo;

  // In the constructor, require a Todo
  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Use the Todo to create our UI
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("${todo.title}"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Text('${todo.description}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Keys in the Stateless widgets class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080860/what-are-keys-in-the-stateless-widgets-class)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the Keys question since it is asking about the whole constructor, not just the parameter named key.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The constructor has two named parameters.
Named parameters are optional by default.
`@required` is an annotation recognized by the Dart analyzer and produces a warning if not passed when invoked at build time (it has no effect at run time).

`:` starts the "initializer list", a comma sparated list of expressions executed before the constructors of the super classes and therefore also before the contructors body.
It is often used to check parameter values using assertions and to initialize final fields with calculated values.
A limitation is, that expressions can't read-access `this.` (implicitely or explicitely) because the object initialization is not completed before the super constructors are executed.

The last element in the initializer is an implicit call to the default constructor of the super class if omitted, or the call to a specific constructor of the current class or the super class if given.

In the example in your question the `key` parameter passed to the constructor is forwarded to the named parameter `key` of the unnamed constructor of the super class.

Answer (score 35):

This is an example to supplement [Günter Zöchbauer's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51013532/). It is the constructor of the [Align](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart#L1504) widget.

```
class Align extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {

  // constructor
  const Align({
    Key key,                                                   // named parameter
    this.alignment = Alignment.center,                         // named parameter
    this.widthFactor,                                          // named parameter
    this.heightFactor,                                         // named parameter
    Widget child                                               // named parameter
  }) : assert(alignment != null),                              // initializer list
       assert(widthFactor == null || widthFactor >= 0.0),      // initializer list
       assert(heightFactor == null || heightFactor >= 0.0),    // initializer list
       super(key: key, child: child);                          // initializer list

  // class variables
  final AlignmentGeometry alignment;
  final double widthFactor;
  final double heightFactor;
```

More notes:

- parameters without the `this.` prefix are variables of the superclass.
- parameters that do begin with `this.` are variables defined in the current class.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my detailed understanding on Flutter constructor

There will be only ONE constructor in a class, but could be multiple factory methods.

1. **Positional Parameters**

These are the traditional parameters which are passed in same sequence as defined in constructor.

> ```
> MyWidget(String param1, int param2) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional $param1, $param2");
> }
> ```

Calling

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed',2,)
```

2. **Named Parameters**

Standard practice followed in flutter like where we quote `param_name:value`. Below is example

> ```
> MyWidget(String param1, {int? param2}) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional $param1, $param2");
> }
> ```

Calling

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed',param2: 2,)
```

3. **Optional Parameters**

The optional parameters are wrapped in square brackets `[ ]`

> ```
> MyWidget(String param1, [int? param2]) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional, $param1, $param2");
> }
> ```

Now as the param 2 is in between `[ ]`, it makes the param 2 optional. so below are 2 ways to call it.

Way 1 : not passing param 2, the constructor will treat it as null if not passed.

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed',)
```

Way 2 : passing both params

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed',123)
```

4. **Required Parameters**

When the parameter is to be passed mandatorily, we can use this by using keyword `required` along with the `{ }`.

**Rule** : `required` **cannot be used with optional params** i.e. `[ ]`. Obviously, if it's a required param, it cannot be wrapped in optional `[ ]`

> ```
> MyWidget(String param1, {required int param2}) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional, $param1, $param2");
> }
> ```

Calling

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed', param2: ,123)
```

5. **Colons**

Colons are mainly used for the constructor parameter initialisation.

**Rule** : Initialisation cannot be done for params, it can only be for variables declared in class `strTxt` in this case.

> ```
> String strTxt;
>
> MyWidget(String param1, int param2) : strTxt = "Some Value" {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional, $param1, $param2, $strTxt");
> }
> ```

Calling

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed', 123)
```

Result : Notice the "Some Value" in `debugPrint` log which we set in `:`

> Positional Optional, Param 1 Passed, 123, Some Value

6. **Body**
   It is simply the content within the curly braces.

[image]

7. **Direct assignment via parameters**

You might recall that in Android and some other languages, we pass the value in parameter and then equate it with class level variable. This is entirely shorten in Flutter by simply using `this.class_level_var_name`. It simply assigns the passed value to that class level variable.

> ```
> MyWidget(this.strTxt, int param2) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional, $strTxt, $param2");
> }
> ```

Calling

```
MyWidget('Param 1 Passed', 123)
```

Result

```
Positional Optional, Param 1 Passed, 123
```

8. **nullable `?` OR `required` declaration**

Declaring nullable is required ONLY when we make the parameter optional `[ ]` or Named `{ }`, for parameter defined as normal, doesn't require the `required` or nullable `?`

Notice `?` in `param2`

> ```
> MyWidget(this.strTxt, {int? param2}) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional, $strTxt, $param2, $strTxt");
> }
> ```

Notice `required`

> ```
> MyWidget(this.strTxt, {required int param2}) {
>   debugPrint("Positional Optional, $strTxt, $param2, $strTxt");
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  //create private named constructor
  MyApp._internal();
  // using this private named constructor by creating the instance of it
  // it must be final so it can't be changed.
  static final MyApp instance =
      MyApp._internal(); // Singleton or single instance
  //factory for the class instance
  factory MyApp() => instance; // returns the instance of the class constructor 

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i will try to write clear code thanks