# Why is there "key" a parameter of some constructors and what is it for?

Tags: constructor, dart, flutter

I keep seeing this in a lot of Flutter code but I have no idea what it does or what the point of it is:

```
TextField(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
    key: _inputKey, // <-------------- what is this?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Keys in the Stateless widgets class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080860/what-are-keys-in-the-stateless-widgets-class)

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Key`, you can tell Flutter that a widget is the same (or not the same) after a rebuild. That's especially important when those widgets hold internal state (e.g. a running animation).

When you add or remove widgets from a list (`Column` or `ListView`) on a rebuild, Flutter does not know which widgets were added, which ones were moved and which ones were removed.  Such a use case is described in the question linked by Rémi.

A `GlobalKey` is a special kind of key that allows you to access the `State` and `RenderObject` (and size) of the widget.

The `AnimatedSwitcher` which allows you to switch out a widget with an animation often requires keyed children to signalize if an animation should occur, or if the widget is the same after a rebuild.