# ListVIew items getting duplicated when trying to append new elements on scroll

Tags: dart, flutter

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I'm trying to generate a list from json data and append the next page data to the current list, when scrollcontroller reaches the bottom.

**Problem**

The items are generated when scrollcontroller hits the bottom but it's also adding some previous element into the List and randomly making duplicate items

E.g: https://streamable.com/5n01f

**MY CODE**

```
    List<MovieJson> movielist = [];

  ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
  int pageindex = 1;
  _MoviePageState() {
    fetchdata(pageindex);
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

 //SCROLLCONTROLLER LOGIC

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        pageindex += 1;
        print(_scrollController.position.pixels.toString());
        setState(() {
          fetchdata(pageindex);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  Future<List<MovieJson>> fetchdata(int index) async {

    final response = await http.get('${tmdb.url_v3}' +
        'trending/movie/week' + //path_param
        '?' + //query_string_options
        '${tmdb.api_key_url}' + //api_key=api_key
        '&page=' + //page
        '$index');

    final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    for (var item in jsonData['results']) {
      MovieJson movie = MovieJson.fromJson(item);
      movielist.add(movie);
    }
    return movielist;
  }
```

Rest of the code is building a ListView with FutureBuild Should I add that too?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the movie already exists in the list before adding it.

```
if(!movielist.contains(movie))
  movielist.add(movie);
```

Comment: just as an alert, this `contains` will only work if `MovieJson` has overrided the `==` operator (and maybe `hashCode` too). ([check this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482866/796963))