# removeAt removes the last item not the item stated in the index

Tags: android, flutter

Hi I have a screen for adding images. I use the multi_image_picker for picking the images. Upon selection of the images, all images picked will be shown in a grid view with a FloatingActionButton on top of each image for removal of each image. The problem is, when I click the button for removing an image, the last image is removed not the one I clicked on. Has anyone experienced this?

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:krakatoa/api/FileApi.dart';
import 'package:krakatoa/components/AssetView.dart';
import 'package:krakatoa/config/Themes.dart' as themes;
import 'package:krakatoa/mixins/SnackBarMixin.dart';
import 'package:krakatoa/podos/User.dart';
import 'package:krakatoa/utils/Common.dart' as common;
import 'package:multi_image_picker/multi_image_picker.dart';

class AddImageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> currentImageUrls;
  final String postUrl;

  AddImageScreen({this.currentImageUrls, @required this.postUrl});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _AddImageState();
}

class _AddImageState extends State<AddImageScreen> with SnackBarMixin {
  List<Asset> _images = [];
  User _user;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add images'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              child: Text(
                "Upload Images:",
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
              child: GridView.count(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisSpacing: 3,
                mainAxisSpacing: 3,
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                children: _renderPickedImages(),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Text('UPLOAD'),
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                ),
                color: themes.primaryColor,
                onPressed: _onUploadBtnPress,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    for (var image in _images) {
      image.release();
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    common.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        _user = user;
      } else {
        _user = User();
      }
    });
  }

  void showProgressAlert() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async => false,
          child: AlertDialog(
            content: ListTile(
              leading: CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: null,
              ),
              title: Text('Processing...'),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      barrierDismissible: false,
    );
  }

  void _onAddImageBtnPress() async {
    List<Asset> resultList;

    try {
      resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(maxImages: 5, enableCamera: true);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("AddImageScreen._onAddImageBtnPress: ${e.toString()}");
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    if (resultList.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _images.addAll(resultList);
      });
    }
  }

  void _onUploadBtnPress() {
    if (_images.isNotEmpty) {
      showProgressAlert();
      _uploadImages();
    } else {
      showSnackBarMessage("No images to upload", seconds: 5);
    }
  }

  void _removeImage(int index, Asset image) {
    debugPrint("INDEX: $index");
    debugPrint("Orig Image: ${_images[index].hashCode}");
    setState(() {
      _images.removeAt(index);
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _renderPickedImages() {
    List<Widget> imageWidgets = [];
    imageWidgets.add(InkWell(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 1,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(
            Icons.add,
            size: 60,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: _onAddImageBtnPress,
    ));
    var ctr = 0;
    for (var image in _images) {
      imageWidgets.add(Container(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            AssetView(image),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: _ImageRemoveButton(
                index: ctr,
                removeItem: _removeImage,
                image: image,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));
      ctr++;
    }
    return imageWidgets;
  }

  Future<void> _uploadImages() async {
    if (_user.id <= 0) {
      showSnackBarMessage("User is not logged in");
      Navigator.of(context).pop("User is not logged in");
      return;
    }
    try {
      await FileApi.uploadImages(widget.postUrl, _images);

      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.of(context).pop("Success");
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      showSnackBarMessage(e.toString());
      Navigator.of(context).pop(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

class _ImageRemoveButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function removeItem;
  final Asset image;
  final int index;

  _ImageRemoveButton({this.removeItem, this.index, this.image});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      mini: true,
      heroTag: "ImageAction_$index",
      isExtended: false,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.close,
        size: 15,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      onPressed: _onPress,
    );
  }

  void _onPress() {
    debugPrint("${this.hashCode}");
    debugPrint("Passed Image: ${image.hashCode}");
    removeItem(index, image);
  }
}
```

Comment: your problem lies on `Asset`, please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52482866/796963)

Comment: Hi I changed it and created a new class with asset passed. Then I created the 2 methods in the link you mentioned but it's still the same

Comment: did you solve it? having the same problem

Comment: Did anyone find the solution I am also facing the same issue
Its working for index greater than zero but when the index zero item that is first item is deleted it removes last item

Answer (score 4):

add  `key: Key(YOUR_LIST.length.toString()),`
having KEY helps with the update of the ListView
that worked for me on ListView.builder

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was driving me crazy!