# 'MyhomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);' in Flutter - what would be a clear explanation with an example?

Tags: key, flutter

In Flutter, what would be a clear explanation with an example?

My confusion is about `key`, as in the code below.

```
MyHomepage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080860/what-are-keys-in-the-stateless-widgets-class

Answer (score 70):

The code is the constructor of the `MyHomepage` widget.

```
{Key key, this.title}
```

It declares two optional named parameters (optional named because of `{}`) where

- the first is of name `key` with type `Key`
- the second is of name `title` with the type of the field `this.title` and automatically initializes `this.title` with the passed value. This is nice syntactic sugar that saves some writing.

`:` starts the initializer list.
The initializer list allows some to execute some expressions before the call is forwarded to the constructor of the super class.

When a class is initialized, read access to `this` is forbidden until the call to the super constructor is completed (until the body of the constructor is executed - in your example the constructor has no body).

The initializer list is often use to validate passed parameter values with `assert(key != null)` or to initialize `final` fields with calculated values (`final` fields can't be initialized or updated later).

`super(key: key)` forwards to the constructor of the super class and passes the parameter `key` passed to `MyHomepage` to the super constructors `key` parameter (same as for `MyHomepage({Key key})`).

Comment: for those who don't know what's the meaning of `super` keyword. `super` is just like `this` keyword that indicates to the parent class.
another point is once we use inheritance with `extends` keyword; constructor of child class will be executed after parent's constructor execution.

Answer (score 51):

Thanks for [Günter's detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52056035/myhomepagekey-key-this-title-superkey-key-in-flutter-what-would-b/52056959#52056959) which helped me at the very beginning. Here I would like to explain the background for this question, and especially the punctuation as syntax a little bit.

The mentioned line of code,

```dart
MyHomepage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
```

should come from the auto-generated [Flutter application boilerplate](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive).

The **complete context** is:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

For me, the **weird punctuation** (curly brackets`{ }` and two colons `:`) is what prevented me from comprehending its syntax.

**Curly brackets** of `{Key key, this.title}`: is the syntax for declaring **optional parameters** while defining function in Dart.

**The first colon** of `MyHomepage(...) : super(key: key)` is a separator that specifies the **initializer list** (`super(key: key)`) of constructor function `MyHomepage(...)`

**The second colon** within `super(key: key)` is the way how you **pass a parameter** to a **named function** (`super()` in this case).

- For example, a function `enableFlags` is defined as follows

```dart
void enableFlags({bool bold, bool hidden}) {...}
```

- To call the function, the way Dart passes parameter to the function, is by declaring `parameterName` before `value`, separated with colon `:`, which is safer for developer than the [Pythonic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pythonic#Adjective) way. The counterpart syntax in [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28Apple_programming_language%29) should be **external parameter.**

```dart
enableFlags(bold: true, hidden: false);
```

I wish this could help.

All the definitions and examples can be found in Dart's [official document](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Comment: I'm new to Flutter/Dart, but from Dart docs I understood `{Key key, this.title}` is the syntax for declaring named parameters not optional parameters (aldo it's true that named parameters are optional by default).
What I'm confused about is the use of `this.title` in a named parameter declaration. As I understant it, this syntax declares a parameter named `title` and also initialises the `title` property of the object with the value passed for the `title` parameter.

Comment: @Sorin I have to say  that the latter is really an ugly syntax even though it looks like more brief.

Answer (score 4):

Flutter uses Keys for a lot of things inside the framework. Since your widget extends StatelessWidget or StatefulWidget, this is the way of your widget having a key so that the framework knows what to do with it (the super function is passing the key to the superclass widget - which can be understood by the framework).

Except for that is only Dart syntax (which is awesome by the way).

You can learn more about Keys here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Another example is the testing framework. Flutter driver needs a key to know which widget to look for and interact with it. With this syntax your widget will have a key and it will work!

Comment: That video, while not perfect, is certainly useful for someone new to flutter trying to figure out what keys in widgets are all about.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just look my pictures including two cases :[image: Only exists initializer list]

[image: initializer list and super.constructor]