# Dar/Flutter constructor structure

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code is from an example from "dartpad.dev" web site. Within the `class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget { ...`, in constructor part, I can't understand what's going on. I've been studying dart for a reasonable time, but still it's hard for me to figure out what's happenning. `required this.title` is OK, however why there are `Key? key` and `: super(key: key)` ?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Key is an optional parameter of the Widget class.
"Key? key" is to allow set a key to your StatefullWidget.
"super(key: key)" is the call to the constructor of the extended class

Comment: I think this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52056959/9930734).