# Don't we ever need Keys if we only have StatelessWidget in our widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

So I believe Key in Flutter is still something many of us either don't use at all, or use it without knowing what it actually is.

So I was learning some about it and It seems like we don't need / we don't have any use of any key if we have stateless widgets in the Widget Tree.

But When I looked at the source code of StatelessWidget, it seems like it has a Key optional parameter in its constructor.

```
const StatelessWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

But what's the use of Key in Stateless widget?

Comment: Checkout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080860/what-are-keys-in-the-stateless-widgets-class

Answer (score 0):

checkout this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Actually you don't need key if all the widgets in your tree are stateless widget.

But If you use stateless widget surrounding a stateful widget which uses a key, you should move that key to the stateless widget.  Check the video for more detail~