# custom widget not refreshing on setState in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have created a custom widget named `CartCounter` But now this custom widget not refreshing on `setState`

On tapping reset I want to change the custom widget value to `0` but its not rebuilding..

What should i do implement to `customWidget` or there is another issue?

```
class _HomeScreen2State extends State<HomeScreen2> {
  int english = 0;
  int maths = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
            'English =' + english.toString() + ' Maths=' + maths.toString()),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CartCounter(
              value: english,
              onChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  english = value;
                });
              }),
          CartCounter(
              value: maths,
              onChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  maths = value;
                });
              }),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                english = 0;
                maths = 0;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Reset'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is my CartCounter

```
class CartCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  final int value;
  final Function(int) onChange;
  const CartCounter({Key? key,required this.value,required this.onChange}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CartCounter> createState() => _CartCounterState();
}

class _CartCounterState extends State<CartCounter> {
late int result;


@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    result=widget.value;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(

          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
        IconButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                result--;
                widget.onChange(result);
              });


            }, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
        SizedBox(width: 60,child: Center(child: Text(result.toString(),style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,)),),
        IconButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                result++;
                widget.onChange(result);
              });
            }, icon: Icon(Icons.add)),

      ],),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to inlcude the code for `CartCounter` it seems like you left that out

Comment: yes it ws left to add...i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `CartCounter` widgets maintain their own internal state (`result`) -- which is initialized in the `initState` method.

The thing is that *initState* is called only once when the widget is first created. So, even if the parent widget rebuilds and passes new value properties to `CartCounter`, the internal result state in `CartCounter` does not automatically update to reflect this new one.(even when calling `setState`)

So, basically, the `CartCounter` *doesn't know* that it needs to update its result when the parent's `english` or `maths` values change.

What you want is to force a rebuild, for that you can use `Keys`:

```dart
Column(
        children: [
          CartCounter(
              key: UniqueKey(), // --> add this to force the widget to rebuild
              value: english,
              onChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  english = value;
                });
              }),
          CartCounter(
              key: UniqueKey(), // --> add this to force the widget to rebuild
              value: maths,
              onChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  maths = value;
                });
              }),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                english = 0;
                maths = 0;
              });
            },
            child: Text('Reset Counter'),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

**See also**

- [What are Keys in the Stateless widgets class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50080860/12349734)

Answer (score 2):

To fix this issue, you can move the initialization of result into the build method. This way, the result value will be updated every time the widget is rebuilt. Here's an updated version of your _CartCounterState class:

```
class _CartCounterState extends State<CartCounter> {
  late int result;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // You can keep the initialization here if needed.
    result = widget.value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Move the initialization here so that it gets updated on each rebuild.
    result = widget.value;

    return Container(
      height: 80,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          IconButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                result--;
                widget.onChange(result);
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 60,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                result.toString(),
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                result++;
                widget.onChange(result);
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While both other answers work fine I would personally simply not have a separate value in your state and always work with the widget's value. This should also fix your issue. Like

```
class _CartCounterState extends State<CartCounter> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      width: 200,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(

          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
        IconButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                widget.onChange(widget.value - 1);
              });


            }, icon: Icon(Icons.remove)),
        SizedBox(width: 60,child: Center(child: Text(widget.value.toString(),style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,)),),
        IconButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: (){
              setState(() {
                widget.onChange(widget.value + 1);
              });
            }, icon: Icon(Icons.add)),

      ],),
    );
  }
}
```